# wrong query being created by Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have this model ,

**ReminderModel.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class ReminderModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_reminders';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

and where I do this,

```
$reminder = ReminderModel::query()
                ->where('id', '=', $reminder_id)
                ->get()
                ->first();
```

Eloquent is generating following query in return - 
`select * from 'user_reminders' where ('0' = id and '1' = = and '2' = 109)`
This is wrong query. Instead eloquent should have created a simple query like this - `select * from 'user_reminders' where ('id' = 109)`

Why is eloquent generating wrong query?

SQL exception -

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user_reminders` where (((`0` = id and `1` = = and `2` = 1))))

Filename: C:\wamp\www\crd\vendor\illuminate\database\Connection.php

Line Number: 647
```

Comment: Can you give information regarding what happens if you try the following:

ReminderModel::find($reminder_id);

ReminderModel::where('id', $reminder_id)->first();

ReminderModel::where('id', $reminder_id)->get()->first();

Comment: Ideally, all these ways to do this should work. They are correct. I cleared `vendors` directory and performed fresh install once again and now same queries working again. So must be some weird crazy issue with `composer update`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a record by its primary key with:

```
ReminderModel::find($reminder_id);
```

Comment: Yes I get the correct results this way. But what's wrong with the way I tried. Shouldn't it work right away ? Like if I want to find by some other column I have to use `where()` instead of find.

Comment: You're using where() correctly, I'm not sure why you're getting such a weird query. What happens when you remove call to query() and just do ReminderModel::where()... ? How did you get the SQL query that gets executed?

Comment: With `ReminderModel::where()` I get this query - `select * from 'user_reminders' where ((('0' = id and '1' = = and '2' = 109))))`. It is thrown as exception by MySQL.  Please see the update in question -

Comment: Ideally, all these ways to do this should work. They are correct. I cleared `vendors` directory and performed fresh install once again and now same queries working again. So must be some weird crazy issue with `composer update`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably its because your $reminder_id varible is somehow corrected. Be sure that it is integer. The cde below works fine.

```
$reminder_id=5;    //example id

$res = ReminderModel::query()->where("id","=",$reminder_id)->get()->first();

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Ideally, all these ways to do this should work. They are correct. I cleared `vendors` directory and performed fresh install once again and now same queries working again. So must be some weird crazy issue with `composer update`.

Comment: So this is a quite weird situation. Maybe you should restart your computer :D

Comment: Nah. I had to clear vendors directory and performed `composer install` again. Still don't know what went wrong with previous `composer update` though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$reminder = ReminderModel::query()
            ->where('id', '=', $reminder_id)
            ->first();
```

Don't use get() with first().